# Alfa (AWUS036H) wont connect to backtrack5 r3

Tags: wireless-networking, backtrack

As the title states, I'm trying to connect my Alfa (AWUS036H) to backtrack5 r3. I've already installed the drivers on my host (windows 7). When I go into VMPlayer and try to disconnect it from the host. I get the error "Connection for my usb device 'Realtek RTL8187_Wireless_Lan_Adapter' was unsuccessful" the device is currently in use. I then tried to disable the device from the host. That didn't work either. How can I get my AWUS036H to connect to backtrack 5 r3?

Even after removing the device, I still get a device busy error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have USB 3.0 it's not compatible with backtrack. Uninstall the Intel USB 3.0 host program from the control panel, then open device manager and for all usb hubs (unless you know which usb port your wifi card is connected to) right click on each and select 'Update Driver software', then click the 'Browse My computer' option, then 'let me pick from a list', and lastly click 'Generic USB'. It will update the USB driver to USB 2.0 making it compatible with Backtrack 5. I tested this on Backtrack 5 r3 under VMware version 5.0.1 build-894247 on Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit 6.1.7601, Service Pack 1. Hope you can understand my crappy instructions!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can setup a rule or filter in VMware to have a device automatically connect to the Guest OS.

You don't actually need to setup windows drivers in the Host OS. When it connects successfully to the guest OS, windows will read it as "VMware USB device".

Try a different usb port, and reconnect while the virtual machine has mouse focus.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an Asus G75 laptop by any chance?

I'm having this issue too, and I've seen it reported at the following posts:

- http://forums.hak5.org/index.php?/topic/27344-alfa-and-wmware/
- http://communities.vmware.com/message/2106113
- http://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?18855-USB-3-Problems
- http://communities.vmware.com/thread/394160
- http://communities.vmware.com/thread/418060

Looks to be like VMWare doesn't support USB 3 correctly and there is no way to downgrade a port to USB 2? It sucks because I have this adapter too and want to use it in a Backtrack VM rather than allowing the non-VM host OS to use it.

Comment: No, It's an Asus K55R.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same setup but I am using VirtualBox instead of VMWare Player.   I am able to get the AWUS036H to work in a BT VM without issue in VirtualBox.   I suggest installing VirtualBox to see if it resolves the issue.